# Issue installing scipy in pyenv virtual environment on MacOS - error related to preparing metadata

Tags: python, macos, pip, scipy, pyenv-virtualenv

When trying to install `scipy` using `pip install scipy` inside of one of my python virtual environments (pyenv-virtualenv) on `MacOS`, I am getting an **error related to preparing metadata**:

```
Collecting scipy
  Using cached scipy-1.8.1.tar.gz (38.2 MB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [192 lines of output]
```

I am running 'pyenv' to management my python version, and 'pyenv-virtualenv' to setup/manage virtual environments.

To get to this point I followed this workflow:

```
1. I made sure to install required build environment prerequisites for pyenv and pyenv-virtual env: `https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki#suggested-build-environment`

2. I installed and configured pyenv and pyenv-virtualenv by following: `https://akrabat.com/creating-virtual-environments-with-pyenv/`

3. I installed python 3.10.0 using `pyenv install 3.10.0` and setup a virtual environment using `pyenv virtualenv 3.10.0 vent_default`.

4. I set the local python environment `pyenv local venv_default`

5. I updated pip `pip install --upgrade pip`

6. I attempted to install scipy `pip install scipy`
```

#######################################################

**The full error script is below:**

```
Collecting scipy
  Using cached scipy-1.8.1.tar.gz (38.2 MB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [192 lines of output]
      setup.py:486: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command ('dist_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/8x/pfvw7cb508j6xybjm2b20rsw0000gn/T/pip-modern-metadata-m3genwjf'), proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
        warnings.warn("Unrecognized setuptools command ('{}'), proceeding with "
      Running from SciPy source directory.
      /private/var/folders/8x/pfvw7cb508j6xybjm2b20rsw0000gn/T/pip-install-r8zj7fhi/scipy_286d49a5892443949de76e5557450d8a/scipy/linalg/_generate_pyx.py:674: DeprecationWarning: The distutils package is deprecated and slated for removal in Python 3.12. Use setuptools or check PEP 632 for potential alternatives
        from distutils.dep_util import newer
      /private/var/folders/8x/pfvw7cb508j6xybjm2b20rsw0000gn/T/pip-install-r8zj7fhi/scipy_286d49a5892443949de76e5557450d8a/scipy/special/_generate_pyx.py:1443: DeprecationWarning: The distutils package is deprecated and slated for removal in Python 3.12. Use setuptools or check PEP 632 for potential alternatives
        from distutils.dep_util import newer
      Running scipy/linalg/_generate_pyx.py
      Running scipy/special/_generate_pyx.py
      Running scipy/stats/_generate_pyx.py
      Processing scipy/cluster/_vq.pyx
      Processing scipy/cluster/_optimal_leaf_ordering.pyx
      Processing scipy/cluster/_hierarchy.pyx
      Processing scipy/ndimage/src/_cytest.pyx
      Processing scipy/ndimage/src/_ni_label.pyx
      Processing scipy/linalg/cython_lapack.pyx
      Processing scipy/linalg/_matfuncs_sqrtm_triu.pyx
      Processing scipy/linalg/_cythonized_array_utils.pyx
      Processing scipy/linalg/_solve_toeplitz.pyx
      Processing scipy/linalg/cython_blas.pyx
      Processing scipy/optimize/_group_columns.pyx
      Processing scipy/linalg/_decomp_update.pyx.in
      Processing scipy/optimize/_bglu_dense.pyx
      Processing scipy/optimize/_trlib/_trlib.pyx
      Processing scipy/optimize/_highs/cython/src/_highs_constants.pyx
      Processing scipy/optimize/_highs/cython/src/_highs_wrapper.pyx
      Processing scipy/optimize/_lsq/givens_elimination.pyx
      Processing scipy/optimize/cython_optimize/_zeros.pyx.in
      Processing scipy/optimize/tnc/_moduleTNC.pyx
      Processing scipy/io/matlab/_streams.pyx
      Processing scipy/io/matlab/_mio_utils.pyx
      Processing scipy/io/matlab/_mio5_utils.pyx
      Processing scipy/_lib/_ccallback_c.pyx
      Processing scipy/_lib/_test_deprecation_def.pyx
      Processing scipy/_lib/_test_deprecation_call.pyx
      Processing scipy/_lib/messagestream.pyx
      Processing scipy/special/_ufuncs_cxx.pyx
      Processing scipy/special/cython_special.pyx
      Processing scipy/special/_ellip_harm_2.pyx
      Processing scipy/special/_comb.pyx
      Processing scipy/special/_test_round.pyx
      Processing scipy/special/_ufuncs.pyx
      Processing scipy/fftpack/convolve.pyx
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).